# Is local multiplayer in Castle Crashers possible using only one profile?

Tags: xbox-360, castle-crashers

Is local multiplayer in the Xbox 360 version of Castle Crashers possible without using separate profiles per player?  For example, if I have several high-level unlocked characters in my profile, would I be able to use them in a local multiplayer game with guests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every character needs to have their own profile. but you can power level the other accounts if you have a higher toon that can fly through the levels

Comment: Lame.  What do you mean by power-leveling the other accounts?  Does everyone share XP gained?  And isn't gaining XP based on number of hits, so if the high-level character flies through the levels, wouldn't everyone gain only minimal XP?

Comment: I also assume there's no way to make a copy of my profile?

Comment: no you cannot copy your profile to the same xbox(and if you copied it to another xbox only one could be on live at the same time)

and yes everyone would only gain minimal xp, but you go through the levels so fast the everyone levels quite fast. I found the level with the catfish boss and the level with the robots and lava on it were the best for doing this sort of leveling.